# Show that $D_{33}$ is not isomorphic to $D_{11} \oplus Z_{3}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

Goal: Show that $D_{33}$ is not isomorphic to $D_{11} \oplus Z_{3}$.

They are both non-cyclic groups of order $66$. The same orders are possible for their elements. Comparing massive Cayley Tables is impractical. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the centre of $D_{33}$?

Comment: What about counting the elements with order $2$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $D_3 \oplus D_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_{12}\oplus\mathbb Z_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463203/prove-that-d-3-oplus-d-4-is-not-isomorphic-to-d-12-oplus-mathbb-z-2?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $D_{11} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \not \cong D_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{11}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562091/show-that-d-11-oplus-mathbbz-3-not-cong-d-3-oplus-mathbbz-11/3162253#3162253).

Answer (score 3):

$D_{33} = C_{33} \rtimes C_2 = \langle a, b| a^{33} = b^{2} = bab^{-1}a = 0 \rangle$. One can see, that every element of it can be written as $a^{n}$ or $a^nb$. Now, lets describe all elements that commute with $b$. $ba^{n}b^{-1} = a^{-n}$ and $ba^{n}bb^{-1} = a^{-n}b$. Thus, only $e$ and $b$ commute with $b$ and so they are the only possible candidates for being in the center. But $b$ does not commute with $a$ and so is no in the center either, which makes $e$ the only element of the center. So $D_{33}$ is centerless.

Now $D_{11} \times C_3$ has $C_3$ as a non-trivial abelian direct factors. And it is known, that abelian direct factors always lie in center. So $Z(D_{11} \times C_3)$ has a non-trivial subgroup and thus is non-trivial. And so, $D_{11} \times C_3$ is not-centerless.

Thus we can conclude, that they are non-isomorphic.

Comment: Did you mean $D_{11}$ in the second paragraph?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes, it should have definitely been $D_{11}$. $D_{33}$ in the second paragraph was at the result of a typo. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $D_{2n+1}$ has trivial center, see here:

[Center of dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469131/center-of-dihedral-group)

In particular, for $n=16$ we see that $Z(D_{33})=1$. On the other hand, 
$$
Z(D_{11}\times C_3)=Z(D_{11})\times Z(C_3)\cong C_3.
$$