# Why isn't $D_3 \times \mathbb Z_{10} \cong D_{10} \times \mathbb Z_3?$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I've looked at this through different angles and can't seem to come up with a good proof for this problem. Both groups have the same order $(60)$. I believe they also have elements of the same order $(1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20)$.

Since $\mathbb Z_{10}\cong \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_2$, by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, I could turn the original problem turns into: $D_3 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_2 \ncong D_{10} \times \mathbb Z_3$, but I can't see how that would be helpful and every proof I've tried so far hasn't worked.

Any tips?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'd say order $60$.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed the typo, thank you

Comment: If you would search this site a bit, you could find ideas for a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463203/prove-that-d-3-oplus-d-4-is-not-isomorphic-to-d-12-oplus-mathbb-z-2?rq=1).

Answer (score 6):

Consider the property

> If $a$ has order $3$ and $b$ has order $2$, then $ab=ba$.

Only one of your groups has this property, the other doesn't. Hence they cannot be isomorphic.